# Accessing Azure storage without providing key and account name in the config

Tags: deployment, configuration

We have a deployment scenario where we don't want to shared Account key and account name. Is there any way i can access Azure storage without providing Account key and account name?

Regards,

Aditya

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Blob storage, you access a store that is marked for public access, or marked for signed access via a Shared Access Signature.

If you're using Table or Queue storage, the authentication headers are required.

You can get more info about Azure storage authentication [by clicking here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179428.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1)  One way is you provide your own interface to Azure.  Others simply don't have direct access to Azure.

2)  If you're providing **read** access to **blobs** you can provide two levels of anonymous public access.  The two levels are to the blobs only and a higher level of access, called Container, which gives reading of blob resources, container metadata, and the list of blobs in the container.

3)  If you have provided name and key to third parties, there is a limited way to recover.  With two keys, if you release only one, you can regenerate it to effectively revoke permission.  *(This option is limited.  You may use the two keys internally, to provide a way to change credentials (for security) from time to time, that makes revocation harder.  If you share with several parties you'll need to re-issue credentials to the others, which might be a bridge too far!)*

4)  There is also an approach called **Shared Access Signature**, for blobs.  This gives fairly granular control, can be time limited, can be revoked... It's more work to implement.